# Can we use Local Scopes in Symfony?

Tags: laravel, symfony, eloquent

I wondering about a subject. We can use Local scopes in Laravel but i don't know if for Symfony.

Doc : [Laravel Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

Well, my question is can i use it in Symfony? Is this possible ?

Have a good day

Comment: That's an Eloquent feature. You would need to use Eloquent within Symfony. Search for "use Eloquent with Symfony". Obviously, you could do similar things with Doctrine's query builder. But that's Doctrine, not Symfony.

Comment: You can use [wouterj/eloquent-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/wouterj/eloquent-bundle)

Comment: You can always use [illuminate/database](https://github.com/illuminate/database) on its own in any project without needing to use all of Laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same with classical methods in your repository.
I can show you an example(using source code from [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-the-query-builder)):

```
    public function findAllGreaterThanPrice(int $price, bool $includeUnavailableProducts = false): array
{
    // automatically knows to select Products
    // the "p" is an alias you'll use in the rest of the query
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.price > :price')
        ->setParameter('price', $price)
        ->orderBy('p.price', 'ASC');

    if (!$includeUnavailableProducts) {
        $qb->andWhere('p.available = TRUE');
    }

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    return $query->execute();

    // to get just one result:
    // $product = $query->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Here instead of return "$query->execute()", you can return $qb and chain methods will available.
You can do something like that :

$repo->findAllActive()->findAllGreaterThan12();

*Here $repo would be the repository injected in your controller.*

In both method, you would have just a where and a return of querybuilder.

Comment: Thank you for answer!